# Need idea on how to query dynamo db for specific date range in node

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Need to design a table in Dynamo DB to get the month-wise data like how many users logged in to the application on a particular time frame as below

1. Today how many users logged in?
2. Particular month how many users logged in?
   3  Particular year how many users logged in?

I am using node js in lambda with dynamo DB. Need help with table design and how to use filter to get the data for the above requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the number of users, the DynamoDB item size for each user, the frequency you want to run these queries, and if you plan to add more analytics queries in the future, and if future queries will be more complex

Comment: Hi @RossWilliams as the app is in the initial stage we are working on 50 users for now. later the user count would be in the thousand. The size will be very less I am planning to save only the user id and login time only. The frequency will be no more than 5 in hr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user items are small, a single query for users can return ~5,000 items (all your users). If you run this every 10 minutes, your monthly on-demand cost is $0.12.

Just query all the users and calculate the metrics on the server, it's not worth the time to design anything more complex.

Comment: Thanks, Ross Williams for the valuable answer.